# Правильная пунктуация в предложении

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь, цитата

**На первый вопрос «Интересуетесь ли вы событиями, произошедшими в годы ВОВ?»  большинство учащихся и все педагоги ответили утвердительно.**

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно оформить с точки зрения пунктуации это предложение.

Answer (score 1):

В связи с распространенностью вопроса лучше оформить его по классическому образцу для прямой речи (прямая речь внутри слов автора, постановка двоеточия):

**На первый вопрос: «Интересуетесь ли вы событиями, произошедшими в годы ВОВ?» ― большинство учащихся и все педагоги ответили утвердительно.**

**Тире** объясняется наличием вопросительного знака и необходимостью выразить соответствующую интонацию.